# Does a profile or summary section make sense for a recent graduate?

Tags: resume

As a recent graduate, the most common is that you don't have experience in the field of study beyond an internship, so I'm wondering whether is it really necessary to add a profile or summary section in the resume, as it will basically a "copy & paste" of the internship's activities.

Comment: While answering I rembered a similar question, whose answers might be helpful to you, too: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/what-should-a-recent-graduate-list-on-a-resume-if-they-have-no-work-experience

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is exactly what it should be. Your internship activities. Not necessarily C'n'P; the **experience section can have the details and the education section can have mentions**.

For a recent graduate a higher level of detail in the education section is imporant too. This part will later be shortened for brevity reasons and because as work experience builds up, it will become less and less important, comparatively. Then the internships will also reduce to side notes in the education section.

For just after having graduated, *put in what you can, in both sections* (as long as you don't turn it into a novel.

Answer (score 1):

As a graduate who has completed intense study and potentially internship level work, all experience is relevant. While you'll have limited employment to list, you will definitely want to list any and all "metric-able" achievements. During your internship, did you do anything relevant to your new career that can be tracked or show advancement? During your studies did you work on any successful projects that provide relevant insight? Employers want to know about your collaborations. Since you're green out of college, all employers are going to be able to accept the fact that you have limited experience. The interview is going to be about how you sell yourself for the position they're "buying" for.

Don't focus on grades, but focus on achievements. Bullet point items such as:

- Led a 4 person undergraduate project team to present evidence of political backlash among disgruntled underwater basket-weavers.
- Explored a thesis in the importance of river-run off and its affect on rural community charity participation.
- Participated during intership for Betterment of Very Apathetic Individuals Charity Fund in leading donations drive - managed to reduce apathy in 400 individuals.

Don't go overboard with it, but provide anything of relevance to an employer that might show how **you** can benefit **them**. Even at an entry level position, you should be able to separate yourself from the other 2,000 applicants in some way. If you can't do that, then you should focus some effort on coming up with a way to do it. There is something about you that makes you valuable, but only you know what it is. Find it, polish it, shine it, and then figure out how to show it off.

We use this in software, but it definitely applies to your resume as well: If you're copying and pasting something, you're probably doing it wrong. Don't copy and paste some job description. Show them **why you**.