# Advice to get my foot in the door as a software developer

Tags: software-industry, career-development, career-switch

Im a recent computer sciences graduate. I picked up an IT job as soon as I got out of university because I needed a job. However its now been around 6 months and Im starting to feel like I need to switch stream because I want to become a software developer (ideally working with Java, Javascript, HTML, CSS) and I don't want to invest too much time in IT as that might likely make switching streams more difficult. It doesn't have to happen tomorrow but I'm willing to do what it takes and I just wanna make sure I'm doing the right things to go down the correct path.

Problem is almost all jobs out there that even get your foot in the door require experience (unless you know someone). I'm looking for any advice to help me switch stream and point me towards the right direction, or to help me stand out among other people who apply for the same positions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Web dev is the easiest transition possible. Just do some website when you got time, and put it on the table when the recruiter will ask for your job experience. You might also want to put "self learning" or something like that on your CV about those technologies. But if you didn't do soft before, why do you want to switch if you don't know how it is ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soo... I need experience to get experience?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21675/soo-i-need-experience-to-get-experience)

Comment: You need internship and don't take the support path, really you don't want to be the support guy. Because once you are the support guy you cannot be developer anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do employers expect from new graduates?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/what-do-employers-expect-from-new-graduates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no secret ingredient to getting an entry-level job: you look around on the internet or wherever you normally look for jobs (local newspapers, employment agencies) and look specifically for "junior" or "entry level" jobs. Those should not require experience. Apply. Interview. Don't get frustrated when you don't get the first job you apply for. Failure to get one job just just means you got one less competitor for the next job. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Thats the sad thing. Atleast from all the positions I see even the junior positions require 1-2 years of experience

Comment: maybe in a services company ?

Comment: They ask for 1-2 years of experience; they may not require it. Good grades in the subject, demonstrated skill on open source projects, etc. can offset lack of experience to some degree. Can't hurt to apply; worst they can do is not respond.

Comment: Remember that experience does not necessarily mean job-experience but programming experience. Programming in your time-off, hobby/university/open-source projects count, too (for entry level jobs).

Answer (score 1):

I find the above answers all helpful, but don't forget to always be on the lookout at your current employer. There may be some small coding work e.g. Scripting in another language. Take it on, it will boost your cv and you never know, maybe at the next employer you will get the chance to move sideways into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested to pursue this inside the company that you are now or generally?

Generally for IT (because you can experiment/learn at home):

- Be good at what you are doing right now
- Do side projects
- potentially contribute to open source projects
- Have something publicly available (Github, Gitlab)

and every now and then apply.
Generally IT has less people than required (demand >> supply) so it is easier to find someone who will give you a chance.

A talk from a person working on the company whose application you are using to read this: "[How to be awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YisbVr69r7U)" is related to your case.